# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 - Getting user claims from multiple providers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, facebook-authentication, google-authentication

I'm still trying to wrap my head around where each piece of the puzzle goes with Identity 2.0, the question I have at the moment is what is the correct place to retrieve the users full name from the claims returned by each provider.

Such as at the moment in my `AccountController.cs` using this:

```
info.ExternalIdentity.Claims
```

If I logged in using facebook, the claim type is "urn:facebook:name", however if I login using my Google plus provider it is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name".

Now I don't want to be doing a a if/else on provider type to get the correct claim as I may have many different provider options each with a different claim type for the users full name, so what is the correct way to do this...and is this the correct place to do this?

Here is the code from my Startup.Auth.cs file, I have a feeling this is part of the puzzle but just need some clarification:

```
 var fb = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AppId = "xxx",
                AppSecret = "xxx",
                Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));
                        foreach (var x in context.User)
                        {
                            var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", x.Key);
                            string claimValue = x.Value.ToString();
                            if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue,  XmlSchemaString, "Facebook"));

                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            };

            fb.Scope.Add("email");

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fb);

            var go = new GooglePlusAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "xxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxx",
                Provider = new GooglePlusAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(GooglePlusAccessTokenClaimType, context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "GooglePlus"));
                        }
                    }
            };
            go.Scope.Add("profile");
            app.UseGooglePlusAuthentication(go);
```